# Detect Pangram Codewars

Tags: c#, data-structures

Task:
A pangram is a sentence that contains every single letter of the alphabet at least once. For example, the sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is a pangram, because it uses the letters A-Z at least once (case is irrelevant).

Given a string, detect whether or not it is a pangram. Return True if it is, False if not. Ignore numbers and punctuation.

My idea:
loop through the characters of the string convert them to lower case letters and add them to the set and when we reach the end of the string we check whether or not set contains 26 letters, if yes then return true otherwise false

My code:

```
private static bool IsPangram(string str)
{
    var set = new HashSet<char>();
    foreach (char ch in str)
    {
        if(ch >= 32 && ch <=41)
         {
                continue;
         }
        if (ch <= 'z' && ch >= 'a')
        {
            set.Add((char)(ch - 32));
        }
        else 
        {
            set.Add(ch);
        }
    }

    bool isPangram = false;
    if (set.Count == 26)
    {
        isPangram = true;
    }
    return isPangram;
}
```

Problem is that my code doesn't work as i expect, and frankly speaking i don't know why help me figure this out

Comment: So what have you done to debug this code? What happens if there are non-alphabetic characters - e.g. digits, punctuation. What results do you get?

Comment: forgot to add this part of the code sorry

Comment: You have the >= <= greater than & less than operators mixed up on the opposite lines and removed the else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why all these arithmetic like `ch <= 41` and then `ch - 32`?

```
private static bool IsPangram(string str) {
  // To be on the safer side of the road, let's check for null
  if (str is null)
    return false;

  // Note, that "set" is a keyword; either use @set or change its name
  var hs = new HashSet<char>(); 

  foreach (char ch in str)
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
      hs.Add(ch);   
    // Do not forget about capital letters
    else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
      hs.Add(char.ToLower(ch));

  // All we have to do is to check if Count is 26 or not
  return hs.Count == 'z' - 'a' + 1;   
}
```

Comment: Now i have a question why is this all math at the return statement, is it wrong to just check against 26 and that is all, or i'm wrong?)))

Comment: @Mark Palik: nothing wrong with `return hs.Count == 26`, but I prefer to have a (tiny bit) safer code: if it was question for some other alphabet `26` wound be wrong and `'z' - 'a' + 1` is easier to adapt